# How to add a reference to a file in an ExeCommand of a custom action?

Tags: wix, wix3.7

During install I want to create a table on a Sybase server. I use the isql command line tool to do that.
I have a script file referenced as Binary because I don't want this file to be installed.
I use a type 34 custom action and I would like to reference my script into my ExeCommand. I've tried to reference the file with a # but it doesn't work..
Here's the code:

```
<Binary Id="SybaseScript" SourceFile="script.sql" />
<CustomAction Id="ExecIsql" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Execute="commit" ExeCommand="[%SYBASE]\[%SYBASE_OCS]\bin\isql -U [DBLOGIN] -P [DBPASSWORD] -S [DBSERVER] -D myDB -i &quot;[#SybaseScript]&quot;" Return="check" >
  NOT Installed
</CustomAction>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="ExecIsql" After="InstallInitialize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: As a way you can create a managed custom action

Answer (score 0):

I reference mine like so:

`ExeCommand="[#MSOFTconfig]"` and `File Id="MSOFTconfig"`